# Extracting Bitmap Data to an array of byte

Tags: c#, image, image-processing, bitmap

Let's say, I have an array of byte containing raw bitmap data without headers.
However the bitmap data is a bit weird, I'm not quite sure but it seems the bitmap data is not correctly aligned if the width is NPOT (Not Power of Two)

I use following codes to construct the bmp from such bitmap data:

```
public Bitmap GetBitmap(byte[] bitmapData, int width, int height)
{
    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format16bppRgb555);
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);
    BitmapData bmpData = bitmap.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bitmap.PixelFormat);
    unsafe
    {
        byte* ptr = (byte*)bmpData.Scan0;
        for (int i = 0; i < bitmapData.Length; i++)
        {
            *ptr = bitmapData[i];
            ptr++;

            if (width % 2 != 0)
            {
                if ((i + 1) % (width * 2) == 0 && (i + 1) * 2 % width < width - 1)
                {
                    ptr += 2;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    bitmap.UnlockBits(bmpData);
    return bitmap;
}
```

The code works fine so far. But for some reasons, I need to implement "Import Bitmap", which mean I need to get the "weird" bitmap data from an instance of bitmap.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I figure out how to do this.

I decide to copy the data first to an array of byte via `Marshal.Copy` and then copy it to another array of bytes while skip some point if the width is NPOT:

```
public byte[] ImportBitmap(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    int width  = bitmap.Width, height = bitmap.Height;

    var bmpArea = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
    var bmpData = bitmap.LockBits(bmpArea, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format16bppRgb555);
    var data = new byte[bmpData.Stride * Height];

    Marshal.Copy(bmpData.Scan0, data, 0, data.Length);
    bitmap.UnlockBits(bmpData);
    bitmap.Dispose(); // bitmap is no longer required

    var destination = new List<byte>();
    int leapPoint = width * 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
    {
        if (width % 2 != 0)
        {
            // Skip at some point
            if (i == leapPoint)
            {
                // Skip 2 bytes since it's 16 bit pixel
                i += 1;
                leapPoint += (width * 2) + 2;
                continue;
            }
        }

        destination.Add(data[i]);
    }

    return destination.ToArray();
}
```